# How to add a Custom field that requires a certain value in civicrm contribution page?

Tags: custom-fields, profile, contribution-page

in my Contribution Page I'd like to ask the donor to accept some privacy rules. For that I'd like to add a custom field into a Profile, add that to the Contribution Page (that works) and only accept the form if the yes/no custom field is answered with a `yes` (radio button).

Is that possible? Is there some other possibility to implement my use case in a Contribution Page?

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to not use a `yes/no`-type of Custom Field, but an alpha-numeric one, choose `check-box` with only one answer as Field Input Type and set the Custom Field as `required` in the Profile that is added to the Contribution Page.

Comment: Yep that is how we tend to do these.